# firefox dropdown list behavior

Tags: javascript, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a list.

```
<select id="select">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>  
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

This line changes the color of the first option item.

```
document.getElementById("select").options[0].style.color = "red";
```

In IE 8 it behaves fine.  In firefox 9.0.1 wierd things happen.  The item as seen from inside the dropdown changes color.  However once that item is selected it returns back to its default color.  I have verified this with jsfiddle in both browsers.  You may visit this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rvUCk/

Can anyone explain the reason for this behavior?  Is there a work around or fix for this?

Comment: What are you looking to do? To me it looks like Firefox is right and IE is wrong. You're changing the color of the first select option which the dropdown does. If you want to change them all, or what the select box shows, style the select element.

Comment: I just need one of the options to be red and stay red selected or not.  As i said IE has the intended behavior.  What do i need to do to firefox to get the same?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your needs. The first element is red always and the others are black. Tested in IE9, Firefox and Chrome:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("select").options[0].style.color = "red";
```

CSS:

```
select {
    color:red;
}
option {
    color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>  
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Demo: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZqan/)**